# Using the FANBOYS "for" in a series

Tags: prepositions, punctuation, conjunctions, mnemonic, coordinating-conjunctions

I have a sentence that is constructed the same as this one:

> She bought food **for** a black cat, a white horse, a red dog, and a green frog.

However, I feel the comma does not give enough pause for what I want to convey. Instead of a series for which the comma is used, I would like more separation between each item when the list is read aloud. That is, each item is more important on its own than in the series.

So I wrote this instead:

> She bought food **for** a black cat, **for** a white horse, **for** a red dog, **and for** a green frog.

I use *for* (from the conjunction mnemonic FANBOYS) in addition to the comma to create the pause I want. Is this so incorrect? Should I just stick with the commas, or is there a better way to represent a longer pause?

Comment: I have no idea what the significance of the word "FANBOYS" is in this context. Care to elaborate?

Comment: "for" of FANBOYS refers to the coordinating conjunction _for_ (He ate, **for** he was hungry), not the preposition _for_ (The food is **for** you).

Comment: FANBOYS is a mnemonic device for *for*, *and*, *nor*, *but*, *or*, *yet*, and *so*.

Comment: @SimonKuang From where? How is that useful? Seems too bizarre. No native speaker has ever been taught that way. Is this some ESL thing?

Comment: @tchrist It's taught in schools to help the students memorize the CCs.

Comment: @SimonKuang In what schools?

Comment: @tch American schools.

Comment: @tch http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/8-3punc.html

Comment: @Simon Kuang You're quite right. However, the FANBOYS approach is broad-brush: for a start, other coordinators exist. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(grammar))  has: 'These are not the only coordinating conjunctions; various others are used, including "and nor" (British), "but nor" (British), "or nor" (British), "neither" ("They don't gamble; neither do they smoke"), "no more" ("They don't gamble; no more do they smoke"), and "only" ("I would go, only I don't have time")...'.

Comment: Have a look at other threads here on ELU, especially Pitarou's answer (and the linked article) [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115821/conjunction-puzzle-is-this-clause-dependent-or-independent/115827#115827). This argues that not all the FANBOYS _are_ coordinators.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/598864/2085).

Answer (score 1):

Your replacement sentence is perfectly grammatical, but quite formal. It sounds like you're using repetition as a rhetorical device, rather than something somebody would say naturally.

But to be honest, your initial sentence comes across as a little unnatural too. Why mention the colours of the animals? Why is this woman buying food for *a cat*, rather than *the cat* or  *her cat*?  If you recast the initial sentence in a more natural way, the ambiguity disappears:

> She bought food for her cat, horse, dog and frog.

Does that help?

Comment: What’s a dog and frog?

Comment: There's no such thing as a *dog and frog*; but the sentence doesn't suggest there is. It simply refers to the woman's four separate animals.

Comment: Add a comma then.

Comment: Not necessary; an [Oxford comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma) isn't used so much in ordinary english (BE) these days.

Comment: It just doesn’t look right without the comma.

Comment: Clearly you use the Oxford comma normally. But this isn't relevant to the OP's question at all.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I have learned several things here. It is nice to know my replacement sentence is formal and is ok to use. The sentence I am planning to use has a similar constrution. I wanted to use a simple sentence to begin my inquiry so the discussion would focus on the english rather than the content.

Comment: Here is the sentence I am planning on using: "They have instituted poor checks and balances for the financial accounting for entitlements, for government department's spending, for foreign aid spending and for military spending."  I would like to hear your comments on this structure. Thanks in advance.