# In the sentence, "I want an air-freshener because I can't stand bad smells", why is the because-clause a subordinate clause?

Tags: grammar, subordinate-clauses, independent-clauses

> *I want an air-freshener because I can't stand bad smells.*

Here, isn't 'I can't stand bad smells' a coordinate clause? It is complete in itself, right? It's only after adding 'because' that the sentence becomes subordinate.
But 'because' is a conjunction. So, if we want to check if a clause is coordinate or subordinate, shouldn't we exclude the conjunction ('because') here?

***Edit***: Thanks to the people who have answered this question! Below, I am writing what I have inferred/concluded from all the answers. I request everyone, to inform if what I understood is correct or not.

- subordinate clauses are necessary in the sentence to convey its full
  meaning, and that coordinate clauses are of greater value/importance than
  subordinate ones.
- Coordinate and subordinate clauses can exist without the help of each
  other, and will make complete sense, but in order to convey the whole
  meaning of the original sentence, it is important to use them both.
- Let's say in this sentence, both are making complete sense on its
  own, but coordinate clauses are more important. "I want a freshener"
  is more important than telling its reason. "I can't stand bad
  smells", which is the subordinate clause in this sentence, *can*
  stand alone, but it is of lesser importance in the original sentence.

Comment: _Withstand_ is a rather odd choice of verb in this context - _stand_ or _bear_ would be more idiomatic.

Comment: @Kate Bunting: That's right. I've edited the question. :)

Comment: See also the analysis at the apparently dissimilar [Why does complex sentence vs compound sentence matter?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146033/why-does-complex-sentence-vs-compound-sentence-matter) (thanks to user405662).

Answer (score 3):

The assumption that *I can't stand bad smells* is a coordinate clause because it is "*complete in itself*" is wrong. Coordination implies joining two (or more) ideas together **that are equal in value.** The grammatical glue to join them is contained in the mnemonic FANBOYS.

But the crux of subordination is to join two sentences together **when one idea is less important (subordinate) to the other.** And to subordinate one idea to another, we use a connecting word called a "subordinator"; *because* is one such subordinator.

In sum, the clause *I can't stand bad smells* is a subordinate clause introduced by the subordinator *because.*

Comment: That's the semantic definition of subordination. But you can't just assume and assert that it's the only one (or the one most grammarians use). At least some supporting evidence needs to be added. // The FANBOYS classification has been shown to be a gross over-simplification of the real situation. It has been debunked, as seen in earlier threads. For instance, 'I want an air-freshener, because I can't stand bad smells' and 'I want an air-freshener, for I can't stand bad smells' look like identical structures using adjuncts of reason.

Comment: So you want to say that subordinate clauses can stand alone also; but when it comes to importance in the particular sentence, they are of less value than coordinate clauses?
But I have also read a definition that said 'Subordinate clauses are dependent on main clauses and can't stand alone. They need a main clause to be able to provide the full information to the user.'
But if so, the "I want an air-freshener" clause is also a subordinate clause, since it doesn't provide the full info to the reader, when it stands alone.

Comment: I would avoid using the mnemonic FANBOYS. Grammarians don't use it because it's out-of-date and inaccurate. Did you get the book I recommended?

Comment: @BillJ: Yes, i do have it here but skim through it on and off due to scheduling problems these days. It is a prized possession: I see reading it (I'm hoping to follow it with CaGEL but right now that appears a long shot) as an organic process, a lifelong association. And thank you very much for being on this wonderful forum: I have learned a lot from the likes of you and other esteemed members here.

Comment: @Manav Tyagi: Edwin Ashworth and BillJ are authorities on such matters: I think they could clear up any further doubts in this regard better than me or most of the folks hereabouts.

Comment: @user405662: Thanks for the info!

Comment: Can anybody please answer my question, which i asked in the reply of this particular answer?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth has answered a similar question here https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146033/why-does-complex-sentence-vs-compound-sentence-matter. Do check it please to see if anything resonates.

Comment: @405662 Was that Me? I'd completely forgotten that one. It still makes sense.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/598864/2085).

Answer (score -1):

Without a subordinate clause the sentence won't be complete. "I want a freshener", why do you want a freshener? To continue the sentence we should use "because" as subordinate clause to complete it as "that I can't stand the smell".

Comment: "Without a subordinate clause the sentence won't be complete. " is simply not true. Of course the first clause can stand alone. And "because" all on its own does not usually constitute a subordinating clause. BTW, not my DV...

Comment: "Because I can't stand bad smells" is an adjunct in clause structure, more specifically an adjunct of reason.

Comment: So you want to say that subordinate clauses are necessary in the sentence to convey its meaning, and that coordinate clauses are of greater value than subordinate ones?